# Sources of Ibn Ezra in England

Tags: avraham-ibn-ezra

I am looking for sources on ibn Ezra's travels and biography. In particular his visit or passage to England. Wiki states the he came to London and Oxford. Where would a more authentic source be found?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) mirab and thanks for this first question. Note that not every question is in scope for this site (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) so this question might be closed - but hopefully this won't deter you from continuing to learn with us.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1450032?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) by M. Friedlander entitled 'Ibn Ezra in England' and published in the Jewish Quarterly Review in October 1895 discusses the topic.